# Reset Laravel 5 Authentication Scaffolding

Tags: php, laravel

Long story short is that I screwed up my authentication scaffolding and would like to know how to completely reset it to the base scaffolding. I tried deleting files however when I ran the appropriate artisan command, it did not rebuild the scaffolding.

The question is, how do I reset the scaffolding to the point where I just ran the "php artisan make:auth" command?

Comment: Are you using version control? You could discard your changes with git.

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 1):

So, Since you're not using any version control then it has became very difficult to track the changes or going back. However you can go to `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Console/MakeAuthCommand.php` file to see what changes `php artisan make:auth` does and undone things.

Here's the content of that file.

```
<?php
namespace Illuminate\Auth\Console;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Console\AppNamespaceDetectorTrait;
class MakeAuthCommand extends Command
{
use AppNamespaceDetectorTrait;
/**
 * The name and signature of the console command.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $signature = 'make:auth {--views : Only scaffold the authentication views}';
/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Scaffold basic login and registration views and routes';
/**
 * The views that need to be exported.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $views = [
    'auth/login.stub' => 'auth/login.blade.php',
    'auth/register.stub' => 'auth/register.blade.php',
    'auth/passwords/email.stub' => 'auth/passwords/email.blade.php',
    'auth/passwords/reset.stub' => 'auth/passwords/reset.blade.php',
    'layouts/app.stub' => 'layouts/app.blade.php',
    'home.stub' => 'home.blade.php',
];
/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function fire()
{
    $this->createDirectories();
    $this->exportViews();
    if (! $this->option('views')) {
        file_put_contents(
            app_path('Http/Controllers/HomeController.php'),
            $this->compileControllerStub()
        );
        file_put_contents(
            base_path('routes/web.php'),
            file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/stubs/make/routes.stub'),
            FILE_APPEND
        );
    }
    $this->info('Authentication scaffolding generated successfully.');
}
/**
 * Create the directories for the files.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function createDirectories()
{
    if (! is_dir(base_path('resources/views/layouts'))) {
        mkdir(base_path('resources/views/layouts'), 0755, true);
    }
    if (! is_dir(base_path('resources/views/auth/passwords'))) {
        mkdir(base_path('resources/views/auth/passwords'), 0755, true);
    }
}
/**
 * Export the authentication views.
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function exportViews()
{
    foreach ($this->views as $key => $value) {
        copy(
            __DIR__.'/stubs/make/views/'.$key,
            base_path('resources/views/'.$value)
        );
    }
}
/**
 * Compiles the HomeController stub.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function compileControllerStub()
{
    return str_replace(
        '{{namespace}}',
        $this->getAppNamespace(),
        file_get_contents(__DIR__.'/stubs/make/controllers/HomeController.stub')
    );
}
}
```